# How to substract 15 minutes from a pandas timestamp that has 'ms' units on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp

Suppose that you have the following `df`:

```
          End Date         Close Price

2022-05-12 09:59:59.999000     0.00711
2022-05-12 10:14:59.999000     0.00704
2022-05-12 10:29:59.999000     0.00712
```

The `['End Date']` was set as the index column of the `df`

When typing:

> `In [1]: df.index[0]`

You get:

> `Out[1]: Timestamp('2022-05-12 09:59:59.999000')`

So, how could you substract 15 minutes from the `df.index[0]` value in order to get the following output?

> `Out[2]: Timestamp('2022-05-12 09:44:59.999000')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out already, it was actually very straight forward:

> `In [1]: df.index[0] - pd.DateOffset(minutes=15)`

> `Out [1]: Timestamp('2022-05-12 09:44:59.999000')`

Source: https://thispointer.com/how-to-add-minutes-to-datetime-in-python/